# How to unmark groups as dead in KGS Go

Tags: kgs-go

I just played a game of Go at the KGS server using CGoban 3 against a beginner. He mistakenly marked a group of mine as dead that was very much alive. I tried clicking on it, but the dead or alive status of the group did not change.

How can I unmark a group as dead? How is it handled if the players disagree about the status of a group of stones?

Comment: It's been years since you posted this but, what's Go and what's KGS?

Comment: @Nitros [Go is an ancient board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29) (I recommend it highly) and [KGS](https://www.gokgs.com/) is a popular server for playing it online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this amazing FAQ page](http://www.gokgs.com/help/faq_en.html?helpLocale=de_DE) - "Revive the stones with shift-click on one of the marked stones. If your opponent insists in marking living stones as dead, ask for a referee in one of the chat rooms: nearly every stronger player is able to settle a dispute of this kind."

Comment: Shift-clicking is something I did not try, thanks.